# Crontab - Python

Tags: python, cron

I am a beginner in Python and Linux. When trying to schedule a python script on crontab file, I face some difficulties. Even simple commands like:

30 16   * * *   root    python --version>/var/log/test.txt

are not working: the file "test.txt" is indeed created but it is totally empty.

Could you please help me identifying the reasons for such problem?

Comment: Try specifying the full path to the python executable (e.g. /usr/bin/python). Cron runs with a very minimal environment, and may not have a good PATH variable.

Comment: You can check the `STDOUT` from the cron-job by checking the local mail spool for the user which this cron belongs to. If it's root or you, log in as that user and type `mail` and hit enter, by default most systems put the `STDOUT` to the mail spool.

Comment: Thanks for the mail tip :). By executing the same command I posted before: 48 17 * * * root  python --version>/var/log/test.txt and checking the mail output in the file /var/mail/mail I can see how the python version is printed Date: Mon, 16 Mar 2015 17:48:01 +0100
Python 2.7.3. Neverheless, my file is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

I may be mixing things up here but why are you putting `root` in front of python? Juts try

```
30 16 * * * python --version > /var/log/test.txt 2>&1
```

I just dropped the `root` part (think it's unnecessary) and added the `2>&1` which also prints the errors into `test.txt`. That way you can see what's going on with your program

Comment: Correct assumption, if you need this to be run as root, you simply do `sudo crontab -e` and thus effectively edit root's crontab jobs. Also the full path to python **might** be required but often not.

Comment: Also check your mailbox by typing `mail` as the user which this crontab belongs to. There you'll find the `STDOUT` of any cron-job not piped like you just wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify the full path to python executable, cron operates with a limited environment. Try to change it to

```
30 16 * * * /usr/bin/python --version>/var/log/test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the python binary with full path:

```
30 16 * * * root /usr/bin/python --version>/var/log/test.txt
```

If unsure about the path, run `whereis python`!